# What's recommended for authentication check? Servlet Filters or Form based authentication?

Tags: authentication, servlets, servlet-filters

We are working implementing Single Sign On(SSO) using [pingfederate](http://www.pingidentity.com/our-solutions/pingfederate.cfm). The basic implementation uses a login token sent via browser cookies for checking user authentication. What's the recommended way of doing the authentication check? Should I use a login filter or configure form-based authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both can be done as good. The difference is only that you've to write all the code yourself in one case and just do some (XML) configuration according existing guidelines in the other case.

Either way, I think the benefits and caveats are obvious enough. In this particular case, I'd go for container managed authentication to avoid future maintenance headaches.

Comment: I was thinking using filters may increase the turn around time(execute filter and then execute servlet) !! I have to test this with sample apps though.

Comment: That's completely negligible. Unless the filter logic itself is poorly written of course. E.g. reading/loading some config file from disk everytime instead of caching it in memory during init and that kind of things. Or did you think that container managed security is doing some magics without any line of code? :)